# Is there a way to get the selected values from text and number filter using AG Grid filter APIs?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an AG-Grid with columns which use text and number filters. I would like to get the array of values selected in these filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSelectedNodes() function to get selected rows, Here an e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-selected-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can access and set the models for filters through the grid API. You can get the state of all filters using the grid API method `getFilterModel()`

Here is a reference to ag-grid [Filter API](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-api/#get--set-all-filter-models)

Here is an [Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#example-custom-filter-options)

**Update**

You can access all the data in grid after the filters have been applied by using `forEachNodeAfterFilter`.

Here's an example of how to use this method:

```
const athletes = [];
this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter((rowNode, index) => {
  athletes.push(rowNode.data.athlete);
});
```

This will give you an array of all the athletes after filters have been applied.

Comment: The filter model looks something like this - 
`{
athlete: {
        filterType: 'text',
        type: 'startsWith',
        filter: 'mich'
    },
    age: {
        filterType: 'number',
        type: 'lessThan',
        filter: 30
    }
}`
But I want an array of selected values. For example, an array of numbers less than 30 or an array or Athletes whose names start with 'mich' .

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer! Yeah, I have already looked into this api and implemented it by storing the column values in a Set to obtain the unique values. But I was not sure how efficient this solution is since we are going over all the rows and I work with a pretty huge dataset. Since the filter model already knows the selected filters, I was wondering if we can fetch it directly from the model instead of doing it manually.

Comment: The `FilterModel` only provides information about the applied filters in the form of an object.
Currently _ag-grid_ doesn't provide any `API` method to get all the rows, so in case you want to access row data you will have to use `forEachNodeAfterFilter`.
You can find more information about it [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/accessing-data/).